# Question on trigonometric linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

Doing an exercise on complex analysis where it began by asking me to solve some equations for $u_x$ and $u_y$ I got stuck and looked up the answer.

> $$u_x\cos\theta+u_y\sin\theta=u_r,$$
>   $$-u_xr\sin\theta+u_yr\cos\theta=u_\theta.$$
>   Solving these simultaneous linear equations for $u_x$ and $u_y$, we find that
>   $$u_x=u_r\cos\theta-u_\theta\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\quad\text{ and }\quad u_y=u_r\sin\theta+u_\theta\frac{\cos\theta}{r}.$$

<sup>(Here's the [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg9ha.png) of this quoted text.)</sup>

The answer says 'solving these simultaneous linear equations'...but surely these are not linear equations when they use cos and sin?

And how do you solve these equations anyway, i can see you can divide across the bottom equation but I can see what to do after that.

Comment: $\theta$, $u_\theta$,   $u_r$, and  $r$ are treated as constants. Note, the  solution  is different for different $\theta$, $u_\theta$, and $u_r$, $r$.

Comment: They're not "linear in $\theta$" since $\sin$ and $\cos$ are involved.  They're linear in $u_x$ and $u_y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equations are linear in $u_x$ and $u_y$—that is, if $\theta$ is a constant, $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ are constants, so they're just like having numbers there.

If you multiply the first equation by $\sin\theta$ and the second equation by $\frac{\cos\theta}{r}$, you'll have
$$u_x\cos\theta\sin\theta+u_y\sin^2\theta=u_r\sin\theta$$
$$-u_x\cos\theta\sin\theta+u_y\cos^2\theta=u_\theta\frac{\cos\theta}{r}$$
Adding these two equations gives
$$u_y(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta)=u_r\sin\theta+u_\theta\frac{\cos\theta}{r}$$
and since $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$, 
$$u_y=u_r\sin\theta+u_\theta\frac{\cos\theta}{r}.$$

You can find $u_x$ from this $u_y$, or by applying a similar technique to the original equations.